# Add server $HOSTNAME to client JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, client, hostname

I have some JavaScript that is run client-side. It includes a websocket address to communicate with the server:

```
new WebSocket("ws://localhost:3000/")
```

All would be well, except that I want 'localhost' to be the `$HOSTNAME` environment variable that is read from the machine I'm using as server. I don't want to hardcode that. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Duh.

```
new Websocket("ws://" + window.location.hostname + ":3000/")
```